# New configuration option and OMNET++ ini error checking

Tags: omnet++

I have added the following configuration option into my C++ code in OMNT++:

```
Register_PerRunConfigOption(CFGID_LOGEVENTS, "logevents", CFG_BOOL, "false", "log scheduler events");
```

I specify the 'logevents' in my `Config <name>`, and I can use it without any issues. The problem is with the ini error checking:

[image]

Apparently it does not recognize the newly added config option and shows an error.  <s>As a temporary workaround, I am using `**.logevent = false` in order to change error into warning.</s>

Is this a known issue ?

Every time I run my project, the following error window pops up which is annoying!

> Error exist in required project(s): Proceed with launch ?

Is there any ways to fix the error or at least suppress it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is not an error. It only means that IDE does not recognize this option. Your option is added correctly. Build your model using `Qtenv` or `Tkenv` and run it, then choose from the menu: `Inspect` | `Available Components` | `Supported configuration options` - the option `logevents` will be visable.

Comment: well, my code works as expected, but every time I run my project I get: Errors exist in required project, proceed with launch. This is annoying!

Comment: To remove this message in IDE go to: `Window` | `Preferences` | `Run\Debug` | `Launching` and select `Always` in `Continue launch if project contains errors`.

Comment: Thanks! I am hoping that this bug get resolved in the next release :)

Comment: It isn't actually a bug. To support the recognizing of new configuration options that are created in the source code, we would need a live-parser within Eclipse that scans the code and automatically updates the Eclipse IDE internals to support auto-completion etc. That is simply not existing at the moment. It would be a great contribution still, if you find the time, maybe you can look into it and try to implement it.